# Openssl C API Sign Message in 32 BIT and Verify Signature in 64 BIT Openssl

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, libcrypto

I have compiled `openssl 1.0.2 with FIPS 2.0.16` Object Module.
I will use it sign some file using a private key and verify the signature using a public key. I will be using `EVP_*` algorithms.

The signing of the file with private key will happen in a Web interface, then the file and the signature will be put into some device where the integrity of file will be validated by verifying the signature using a public key.

1. Now my question is that the web interface will have a `64 BIT libcrypto.a` and the device where signature is verified may have `32/64 BIT libcrypto.a` so will the signature generated for both `64/32 bit` will same ?
2. Can i sign using `64 BIT libcrypto.a` and verify the signature using a `32 BIT libcrypto.a`?

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit libcrypto. You can create a signature with one and verify it with the other, and vice versa.

> Now my question is that the web interface will have a 64 BIT libcrypto.a and the device where signature is verified may have 32/64 BIT libcrypto.a so will the signature generated for both 64/32 bit will same ?

It depends what you mean be the "same". As I said above it makes no difference whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit libcrypto. The algorithms used are the same. However not all signature algorithms are determinisitic, i.e. some algorithms such as DSA and ECDSA include a random component in the signature. Therefore if you sign the same data twice with the same key you may get different results. Both signatures would be valid however and both would verify.

Comment: Thanks Matt I will check and let you know the output.